# Filter google maps api autocomplete api results to get only airport details like I show below?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Here's my problem.. I'm trying to get filtered my autocomplete results to get only airport addresses as suggestions.. please see the image I have attached.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&type=airport" async defer></script>
```

[image: I found this in a website]

Comment: Your picture is not of only airports

Comment: Of course, There may be hospital results also. But, How can I get My results like that. I have tried as 'types='airport' in URL. but it returns all. may be filtering was not happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request for this in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3538

However, it looks like Google team didn't set a high priority on this task.

You can star the public issue to express your interest and receive future updates.